# Ways to setup Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I just finished building my computer for the first time and I'm hoping to run Ubuntu or at least a Linux dist on it. Currently I have Windows 7 installed on my computer and my question is that how should I install Ubuntu? I have my W7 installed on my 128GB SSD and I have two 1TB HDD; one for progams and the other one for regular files.

Should I install it with Windows on the SSD? 
Install it on a HDD? Or how does dual boot work?
Install it on a USB?

What's a good way to install Ubuntu for a person that is completely new to Linux like me? Sorry if I sound ambiguous, I'd be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Also, is Ubuntu a good distribution to start with if I want to get familiar with what Linux really is? My goal is to learn how to develop a Linux based OS for multiple devices, not implying that I have the ability or knowledge to but I want to start somewhere. Does anyone have any recommended links or readings that can start me off on a right track?

Answer (score 2):

Glad to hear, that you are interessted in open alternatives.

Ubuntu is not problematic to install at all. I would install it on the SSD as dual boot on a partition of 30GB (maybe less, if you're just trying Ubuntu).

Just download the ISO image of Ubuntu or Kubuntu, burn it to CD-ROM and boot from it. You could use an USB stick to boot from, too. Therefore you could use the program "unetbootin" (it can download the latest image, write it to the USB stick and make it bootable).

The setup process is very self-explaining. In particular you just have to know how to [partition a harddisk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition). I would set the "noatime" flag for your SSD, since it reduces harddisk access for read operations. But this is not necessary.

Once the system is set up, you can install new programs from the Ubuntu repository via Synaptics or via console per `sudo apt-get install packagename`.

You can make [further optimizations](http://itezer.com/blog/ubuntu-linux/125-four-tweaks-for-using-ubuntu-with-ssd.html) for your SSD if you want.

Comment: Also, if the two hard disks are internal, you should be able to tell Ubuntu to use one of them as /home during the install, which  would set it up so that your user directory was stored there.

Comment: And is there a specific format that I should configure one of my internal hard disks to? Right now it is in NTFS.

Comment: Sorry for double posting, if I do dual boot and install Ubuntu on my SSD, can I also install my programs onto the hard disk (programs only) and put my files onto the other hard disk (files only) like how I did for Windows 7?

Comment: there is no need to configure the hard disk. Ubuntu's installer would take care of that for you. And you second comment is also possible.